# i need to add Change application language in app using flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

-- i need to add change language option to change language in dynamic.
-- not a create particular language json file to change language.

-- change language in all app using flutter
-- i need to change application language in our app in dynamically

-- i am trying to create this extention to change language but it can been change properly

```
AutoLocalBuilder translates({
    TextAlign? textAlign,
    TextStyle? style,
    int? maxLines,
    TextOverflow? overflow,
  }) {
    return AutoLocalBuilder(
        text: [this],
        builder: (tw) {
          return Text(
            tw.get(this),
            overflow: overflow,
            maxLines: maxLines,
            style: style,
            textAlign: textAlign,
          );
        });
  }
}`
```

Comment: What do you precisely want to achieve, what is the problem you're having currently and what are the tools you're using in this code snippet?

Comment: now i am using translator package to change application language  but it's not work properly so please help to solve this issues.
also i have try to use easy_localization package but i have face same issues.

Comment: You can use this package [flutter_localization](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_localization)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to create an extension method in Flutter for dynamically changing the language of your app. To achieve this, you can use the Localizations class along with Locale to dynamically change the language.